# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'name.length')

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am new to react-native and I am facing the above error in my code.

**The error I faced is:**

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'name.length')

This error is located at:

```
in ProductCard (created by ProductList)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by ProductList)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
in AnimatedComponent
in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by TouchableOpacity)  
in TouchableOpacity
in Unknown (created by ProductList)
in ProductList (created by CellRenderer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by CellRenderer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by CellRenderer)
in VirtualizedListCellContextProvider (created by CellRenderer)
in CellRenderer (created by VirtualizedList)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by ScrollView)
in RCTScrollView (created by ScrollView)
in ScrollView (created by ScrollView)
in ScrollView (created by VirtualizedList)
in VirtualizedListContextProvider (created by VirtualizedList)
in VirtualizedList (created by FlatList)
in FlatList (created by ProductContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by ProductContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by ProductContainer)
in ProductContainer (created by App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by App)
in $dac019021ac61f1f$export$9f8ac96af4b1b2ae (created by NativeBaseProvider)
in ToastProvider (created by NativeBaseProvider)
in PortalProvider (created by NativeBaseProvider)
in HybridProvider (created by NativeBaseProvider)
in ResponsiveQueryProvider (created by NativeBaseProvider) 
in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)   
in SafeAreaProvider (created by NativeBaseProvider)      
in NativeBaseConfigProviderProvider (created by NativeBaseProvider)
in NativeBaseProvider (created by App)
in App (created by ExpoRoot)
in ExpoRoot
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
```

##### **ProductCard.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Dimensions,
    Image,
    Text,
    Button
} from 'react-native'
var { width } = Dimensions.get("window");
const ProductCard = (props) => {
    const { name, price, image, countInStock } = props;
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image 
            style={styles.image}
            resizeMode="contain"
            source={{uri: image ? image : 
'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/04/01/17/29/box-23649_968_720.png'}}
            />
            <View style={styles.card}/>
            <Text style={styles.title}>
                {name.length > 15 ? name.substring(0, 15 - 3)
                    + '...' : name
                }   
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.price}>${price}</Text>   
            { countInStock > 0 ? (
                <View style={{ marginBottom: 60 }}>
                    <Button title={'Add'} color={'green'} />
                </View>
            ) : <Text style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>Currently Unavailable</Text>}
        </View>
    )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        width: width / 2 - 20,
        height: width / 1.7,
        padding: 10,
        borderRadius: 10,
        marginTop: 55,
        marginBottom: 5,
        marginLeft: 10,
        alignItems: 'center',
        elevation: 8,
        backgroundColor: 'white'
    },
    image: {
        width: width / 2 - 20 - 10,
        height: width / 2 - 20 - 30,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        position: 'absolute',
        top: -45
    },
    card: {
        marginBottom: 10,
        height: width / 2 - 20 - 90,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        width: width / 2 - 20 - 10
    },
    title: {
        fontWeight: "bold",
        fontSize: 14,
        textAlign: 'center'
    },
    price: {
        fontSize: 20,
        color: 'orange',
        marginTop: 10
    }
})
export default ProductCard;
```

**ProductList.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, View, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import ProductCard from './ProductCard';
var { width } = Dimensions.get("window");
const ProductList = (props) => {
    const { item } = props;
    return(
        <TouchableOpacity style={{ width: '50%' }}>
            <View style={{ width: width / 2, 
                backgroundColor: 'gainsboro'}}
        >
            <ProductCard {...item} />
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
export default ProductList;
```

**ProductContainer.js:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator, FlatList } 
from 'react-native'
import ProductList from './ProductList';
const data = require('../../assets/data/products.json');
const ProductContainer = () => {
    const [products, setProducts ] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        setProducts(data);
        return () => {
            setProducts([])
        }
    }, [])
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Product Container</Text>
            <View style={{marginTop: 100}}>
            <FlatList
                horizantal
                data={products}
                numColumns={2}
                renderItem={(item) => <ProductList
                key={item.id}
                item={item}/>}
                keyExtractor={item => item.name}
            />
            </View>         
        </View>
    )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flexWrap: "wrap",
      backgroundColor: "gainsboro",
    },
    listContainer: {
      width: '100%',
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: "row",
      alignItems: "flex-start",
      flexWrap: "wrap",
      backgroundColor: "gainsboro",
    },
    center: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
});
export default ProductContainer;
```

**App.js**

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NativeBaseProvider } from 'native-base'; 
//Screens
import Header from './Shared/Header'
import ProductContainer from './Screens/Products/ProductContainer'
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Header />
      <ProductContainer />
    </View>
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

**Header.js:**

```
import React from "react"
import { StyleSheet, Image, SafeAreaView, View } from "react-native"
const Header = () => {
    return(
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.header}>
            <Image
                source={require("../assets/Logo.png")}
                resizeMode="contain"
                style={{ height: 70 }}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    header: {
        width: "10%",
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignContent: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        padding: 20,
        marginTop: 40
    }
})
export default Header;
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "animal-feedmart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
  "start": "expo start",
  "android": "expo start --android",
  "ios": "expo start --ios", 
  "web": "expo start --web",
  "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
  "expo": "~44.0.0",
  "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0", 
  "native-base": "^3.3.7",
  "react": "17.0.1",
  "react-dom": "17.0.1",
  "react-native": "0.64.3",
  "react-native-base": "^1.1.0",
  "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.2.1",
  "react-native-svg": "^12.3.0",
  "react-native-web": "0.17.1"
  }, 
  "devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
  }
```

Can anyone help me to fix this error. I am ready to provide other details of my code also.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The prop `name` passed to the component `ProductCard` is null.

Comment: Can you tell me what should I change in my code??

Comment: Provide the code from where you're calling this component.

Comment: I had one small doubt @General Grievance i.e if I remove blank spaces then my code looks clumsy which is not able to understand . You already mentioned that you formatted the code. Can you tell me is it ok to remove blank spaces in my code after formatting??(I dont know anything about this as I am new to the community ) It will be helpful if you clear my doubt.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the ProductCard.js code, you are [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the props to multiple variables and create the **name** variable.

From what you are describing, the name variable is expected to be a String (which have the *length* property), but the name variable actually contains undefined or is not passed to the react component as a prop.

You should look at the code calling this react component and validate the content of the props you are passing to (especially, validating that it is a list).

You can also add some defensive code in order to not crashing your program in this kind of situation (for example, validating the name is a String before checking his length - i.e. *name && name.length > 15*)

Feel free to attach the code calling this react component so we can point you to the exact line of code.

Comment: Now I attached the code can you please rectify it. If you want any other details I will provide it. And I want to mention that I am a newbie to react native I am doing this project based on udemy course. I had followed all the instructions of my tutor but still it is giving error. Please provide the solution to my error .I am struck here from nearly 10 days

Comment: @ShaikNaheedaparveen
Based on your code, the ProductList component is calling the ProductCard component with {...items} as props.
You should validate that the props you are passing to the ProductCard includes every props you are using in the ProductCard component (name, price, image, countInStock)

Comment: @ShaikNaheedaparveen pls attach the all of your code if you need us to take a look (and pls fix the formatting)
From what I see, the App.js is calling the ProductContainer component but I cant find what is this component and who is calling the ProductList

Comment: Now I had attached all the code I request you to please once go through it and rectify it. And I want to mention one thing that till now the code worked well but when I installed native-base package it arises all these errors and I request you once again to rectify the code as soon as possible as I need to complete this project within few days. If you need any further details I am ready to provide it.